# Imputation - Using R to distribute values with unlabelled variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I have some values for unknown categories that I want to distribute. In the example I created below where I am looking at counts of hogwarts students in two years (1991 and 1992)  from four houses (gryffindor, slytherin, ravenclaw, and hufflepuff), two genders, who own one of three pets (toad, owl, or cat). So, for example, the first line says that in 1991, there were two male gryffindor students who owned a toad.

However, I also have cases where the gender AND/OR the pet are not known. For example, I know that there are 10 students in gryffindor in 1991 who owned toads, but I don't know what gender they are. I want to distribute those 10 students into the two genders, based on the proportion of male and female gryffindor students who owned toads in 1991. Among the counts of toads owned by Gryffindors in 1991 where the gender is known, males owned 25% of toads(2/8) and females owned 75% of toads (6/8), so I would add 25% of the ten toads to the male count (making the total count of male gryffindors who owned toads in 1991 = 4.5) and add 75% of the ten toads to the female count (making the total count of female gryffindors who owned toads in 1991 = 13.5).

I would use this same logic for cases where I know the gender but not the type of pet owned, and in cases where I know the year and the house, but not the gender or the type of pet owned.

```
DF <- read.table(text = "year house  gender  pet  count
1991  gryffindor  male  toad  2
1991  gryffindor  male  owl 4
1991  gryffindor  male  cat 0
1991  gryffindor  female  toad  6
1991  gryffindor  female  owl 6
1991  gryffindor  female  cat 4
1991  gryffindor  unknown toad  10
1991  gryffindor  unknown owl  2
1991  gryffindor  unknown cat 4
1991  gryffindor  male  unknown 20
1991  gryffindor  female  unknown 16
1991  gryffindor  unknown unknown 12
1991  slytherin  male  toad  4
1991  slytherin  male  owl 2
1991  slytherin  male  cat 2
1991  slytherin  female  toad  6
1991  slytherin  female  owl 2
1991  slytherin  female  cat 4
1991  slytherin  unknown toad  2
1991  slytherin  unknown owl  4
1991  slytherin  unknown cat 4
1991  slytherin  male  unknown 22
1991  slytherin  female  unknown 14
1991  slytherin  unknown unknown 14
1991  hufflepuff  male  toad  2
1991  hufflepuff  male  owl 2
1991  hufflepuff  male  cat 0
1991  hufflepuff  female  toad  0
1991  hufflepuff  female  owl 3
1991  hufflepuff  female  cat 4
1991  hufflepuff  unknown toad  4
1991  hufflepuff  unknown owl  2
1991  hufflepuff  unknown cat 4
1991  hufflepuff  male  unknown 28
1991  hufflepuff  female  unknown 10
1991  hufflepuff  unknown unknown 12
1991  ravenclaw  male  toad  2
1991  ravenclaw  male  owl 4
1991  ravenclaw  male  cat 2
1991  ravenclaw  female  toad  6
1991  ravenclaw  female  owl 8
1991  ravenclaw  female  cat 8
1991  ravenclaw  unknown toad  2
1991  ravenclaw  unknown owl  2
1991  ravenclaw  unknown cat 4
1991  ravenclaw  male  unknown 16
1991  ravenclaw  female  unknown 18
1991  ravenclaw  unknown unknown 14
1992  gryffindor  male  toad  2
1992  gryffindor  male  owl 4
1992  gryffindor  male  cat 8
1992  gryffindor  female  toad  2
1992  gryffindor  female  owl 2
1992  gryffindor  female  cat 4
1992  gryffindor  unknown toad  2
1992  gryffindor  unknown owl  4
1992  gryffindor  unknown cat 4
1992  gryffindor  male  unknown 20
1992  gryffindor  female  unknown 14
1992  gryffindor  unknown unknown 12
1992  slytherin  male  toad  2
1992  slytherin  male  owl 4
1992  slytherin  male  cat 0
1992  slytherin  female  toad  6
1992  slytherin  female  owl 2
1992  slytherin  female  cat 4
1992  slytherin  unknown toad  2
1992  slytherin  unknown owl  2
1992  slytherin  unknown cat 4
1992  slytherin  male  unknown 20
1992  slytherin  female  unknown 16
1992  slytherin  unknown unknown 12
1992  hufflepuff  male  toad  2
1992  hufflepuff  male  owl 4
1992  hufflepuff  male  cat 0
1992  hufflepuff  female  toad  6
1992  hufflepuff  female  owl 8
1992  hufflepuff  female  cat 4
1992  hufflepuff  unknown toad  4
1992  hufflepuff  unknown owl  2
1992  hufflepuff  unknown cat 4
1992  hufflepuff  male  unknown 22
1992  hufflepuff  female  unknown 18
1992  hufflepuff  unknown unknown 12
1992  ravenclaw  male  toad  2
1992  ravenclaw  male  owl 6
1992  ravenclaw  male  cat 0
1992  ravenclaw  female  toad  6
1992  ravenclaw  female  owl 2
1992  ravenclaw  female  cat 4
1992  ravenclaw  unknown toad  2
1992  ravenclaw  unknown owl  2
1992  ravenclaw  unknown cat 8
1992  ravenclaw  male  unknown 10
1992  ravenclaw  female  unknown 20
1992  ravenclaw  unknown unknown 14",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Any suggestions on the most efficient way to code this in R?

Comment: Sounds like you want to impute missing data. The `Amelia` package is classic, but see the CRAN task view on [Missing Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MissingData.html), especially the Multiple Imputation section.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor, that's exactly what I want to do (I'm missing my words today!) I've heard of the Amelia package but never used it before, and am reviewing the pdf now. Any sample code would still be appreciated, but thanks for getting me on the right track!